# using php code inside html page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cordova

I have problem I use several php codes inside html page and it gave me wrong result like this code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Form</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post">

<input type="text" name="int1" /> 
+ 
<input type="text" name="int2" />
= 
<?php
if (isset($_POST)) {
    $int1 = $_POST['int1'];
    $int2 = $_POST['int2'];
    echo $int1 + $int2;
}
?>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Get Sum" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

the right result is calculate the numbers and display it here is no thing display

the other code

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<ul> 
<?php for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){ ?>
<li>Menu Item <?php echo $i; ?></li> 
<?php } ?>
</ul> 
</body>
</html>
```

the right result to display like this

```
Menu Item 1
Menu Item 2
Menu Item 3
Menu Item 4
Menu Item 5
```

but when I display the page just display like this

```
Menu Item
```

that is meaning the php code didn't work in the page

I don't know what is the solution I want to use php code and php functions inside html page 
because phonegap.com not accept php page

Comment: What is your php server?

Comment: Do you really save the changes in file? ;)

Comment: Are you making Javascript app with PHP?

Comment: see here http://saudicpi.com/index.html  PHP version 5.3.27

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run PHP in PhoneGap. PhoneGap loads a local html file in a native webview. You need to have PHP installed to run PHP and this not possible from a mobile device, even if you use native code.

You need to use JavaScript for the typr of processing you are looking for.

Comment: that it will be problem in my project .

Comment: if i want to connect to the database in my application what is the best way

Comment: You can create a local database on the device using websql or you can create an api to interface with a remote server

Comment: I have websql but how to connect without php language

Comment: There is nolonger a plugin for this, but the code in this doc is correct. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

Answer (score 0):

PHP code is processed only in PHP files ( files with `.php` extentions). If your file is `.html`, try to rename it. In your case the PHP not processed and you see anly first `li`.

Also I recommend to you set `error_reporting = E_ALL` in `php.ini` config and restart server. And then you will see what happened with your script

and better use:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<ul> 
<?php for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) : ?>
<li>Menu Item <?php echo $i; ?></li> 
<?php endfor; ?>
</ul> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wrong. It depends on server configuration, you can make file with any extension to work like php script, e.g. with `AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html` for Apache

Comment: Yes, thanks. But I don't think that autor of question is do it for `.html` files

Comment: And I don't think it's a reason to write nonsense like "PHP code is processed only in PHP files"

Comment: @Mesho Try to rename file from `i.html` to `i.php`, please? Your PHP interpreter do not process PHP code in this file, it that I wrote in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your first code does not return anything because your `isset` is not set.

**First code:**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['int1']) && isset($_POST['int2'])) {
    $int1 = $_POST['int1'];
    $int2 = $_POST['int2'];
    echo $int1 + $int2;
}
?>
```

**Second code:**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<ul> 
<?php 
for($a = 1; $a <=5; $a++){
echo "<li>Menu Item ".$a."</li>";
}
?>
</ul> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** After closer inspection it looks as though your code is not being parsed, rename your index.html to index.php

If you view the source you can see the PHP code.

---

It could be your first section failing..

`$_POST` is always set but it can be `empty`

Try this

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['int1'], $_POST['int2'])) {
    $int1 = $_POST['int1'];
    $int2 = $_POST['int2'];
    echo $int1 + $int2;
}
?>
```

`isset()` can take multiple arguments

Comment: It is definitely the fact you are serving a html page and not php. You need to be running on a php enabled server.